# JQuery How do I make <tr> behave as link with standard right click context menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, click

I am currently using this code with JQuery

> javascript

```
$(".row-link").click(function(evt) {
    window.location = $(this).data("href");
});
```

> html

```
<tr class="row-link" data-href="link.html">
        <td>Link</td>
        <td>same link</td>
</tr>
```

This works for making the entire table row clickable as a link, but since javascript is handling it, the standard right click context menu for links in the browser doesn't show up.

I need to be able to have the right click menu for open in new tab. The table it is in is dynamically generated and the results can be up to 4000. I don't want to program in a ctrl+click or a custom right click menu, I just need the table row to be recognized as a link in the browser.

Comment: just refactor to anchors and hrefs

Comment: The problem with that is when there is a result giving around 4000 results, each td element would have to have the anchor and that would be a huge mess of code. I have more <td>s then I posted. It looks like I'm going to have to go that route though...